# .change(function) can control two command

Tags: javascript, jquery

dear all..i've a textfield, it using barcode scanner for input data..after scan it shows KD-R411ED 105X0001...
I'm successful separate them into two text field use ".change(function)"

```
$("#tags1").change(function() {
  var barcode;
  barCode=$("#tags1").val();
  var data=barCode.split(" ");
  $("#tags1").val(data[0]);
  $("#tags2").val(data[1]);
});
```

what i want is beside make them separate after ".change(function)" another script can read two character behind "KD-R411ED"..that is "ED"..this character can make a radiobutton which id="check1" are checked..

what's code which can combine with code above?

this my complete code..

```
$("#tags1").change(function() {
                                 var barcode;
                                 barCode=$("#tags1").val();
                                 var data=barCode.split(" ");
                                 $("#tags1").val(data[0]);
                                 $("#tags2").val(data[1]);

                                 var code = data[0].substr(data[0].length - 2); // suggested by Jan Willem B

                                 if (code =='UD')                                                                     $('#check1').attr('checked','checked');
                                                } else {
                                                        if (code == 'ED') {
                                                                        $('#check2').attr('checked','checked');
                                                }
                                                 }
```

and this the form

```
<input id="check1" type="radio" class="check" name="check" onclick="addtext()" value="U" />U
<input id="check2" type="radio" class="check" name="check" onclick="addtext_1()" value="E" />E
```

the radiobutton still not response

Comment: I think you need to clarify. What you want in the end is <input type="radio" id="check1" value="ED" checked /> or do you want <input type="radio" name="ED" id="check1" value="ED" checked /> OR do you want something else?  What is the "ED" for?

Comment: i want 
<input type="radio" id="check1" value="ED" checked>
if inside textfield there are consist of "ED" character..this ED is for make choise tuner version..if consist of JD ..
<input type="radio" id="check2" value="JD" checked>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you mean,

```
$("#tags1").change(function() {
  var barcode;
  barCode=$("#tags1").val();
  var data=barCode.split(" ");
  $("#tags1").val(data[0]);
  $("#tags2").val(data[1]);

  var code = data[0].substr(data[0].length - 2); // suggested by Jan Willem B

  if (code == 'ED') {
     $('#check1').attr('checked','checked');
  }
});
```

Comment: YUPZ...like that!!
how if show JD?? can it like this?
if (code == 'JD') {
     $('#check2').attr('checked','checked');
  }

Comment: how about this..it refers from Jan Willem B answer..how to read ED character if text like KD-R411H2EDT? may be need some manipulation in that answer??

Answer (score 0):

To read the last two characters:

```
var code = data[0].substr(data[0].length - 2);
alert(code);
```